# Время жизни объекта

Tags: gwt, javascript, java

Как можно убедиться, что объект еще существует? Как сделать так, чтоб объект существовал в определенный момент? Есть такой код:

```
public void onMouseDown(MouseDownEvent event) {
    final MouseDownEvent e = event;
    timer = new Timer() {           
        @Override
        public void run() {
             int x = e.getX();
             int y = e.getY();                
        }             
    };
    timer.schedule(timeDelay);
}
```

В итоге, на вызове `int x = e.getX();` падает с ошибкой.

> (TypeError): Cannot read property 'clientX' of null arguments: clientX, type: non_object_property_load

Как правильно сделать, чтобы после срабатывания таймера получить доступ ко **всем** полям объекта `MouseDownEvent`?

Возможно ликак скопировать объект (подобие `clone`)?

Пробовал сделать подкласс и переопределить некоторые поля, не помогло. Видимо, надо, либо все переопределять, либо искать другой путь.

Comment: Больше похоже на какой-то баг где-то в GWT.

Comment: У меня gwt 2.3.0.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что вы, разумеется, проверили, что e != null на самом деле?

Comment: Да. Только проблемы это не решает :(

Comment: Поместите final MouseDownEvent e = event; внутрь timer = new Timer(),
а то ведь и в самом деле в момент срабатывания таймера на объект MouseDownEvent ссылок ни от куда уже может и не быть.

Вы меня сильно не бейте за это предположение, Java и GWT я только начинаю осваивать.

Comment: Второй event - это просто избыточность. Скорее всего, имелось ввиду, что сам параметр final для использования в анонимном классе, т.е. 

public void onMouseDown(final MouseDownEvent event)

Comment: К Java memory model это отношения не имеет. Исключение произошло уровнем ниже.

Comment: А что за библиотека, если не секрет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уж и не знаю, баг ли это в самом деле или какая-то фича, призванная ускорить обработку событий, но выбор у вас невелик. Вам придётся извлечь необходимые сведения из события до запуска таймера и в обработчике таймера использовать уже их.

**UPD** это не баг. Так и задумано. Вот выдержка из документации по [GwtEvent](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/event/shared/GwtEvent.html):

> All GWT events are considered **dead** and **should no longer be accessed** once the HandlerManager which originally fired the event finishes with it. That is, **don't hold on to event objects outside of your handler methods**.

Так что после того, как обработка события закончилась, объект не может быть переиспользован. Это вызвано применением паттерна проектирования "приспособленец", который в данном случае очень уместен.

Как я уже говорил, у вас нет выхода. Вы не можете использовать это событие в таймере. Библиотека, которую вы используете должна уметь работать без события. Или не используйте таймер.

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня надстройка над другой библиотекой, и туда надо передать объект `MouseDownEvent`, после некоторого времени + достижении опред. условий. Мне нужен именно весь объект.

Answer (score 3):

Проверка на e != null здесь не в тему. Если ставить условие, то e.isLive().

Использование GwtEvent в качестве параметра в библиотеке может быть либо нарушением контракта GWT, либо сознательным запретом на вызов метода из callback, timer, scheduler, и др. Т.к. об этом явно сказано в документации. В общиx случаяx, если xотят сообщить, что  событие можно передавать в качестве параметра в любой момент, используют NativeEvent, а не GwtEvent. Специально для этого создан метод createMouseDownEvent в [Document](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Document.html). А также NativeEvent можно получить из GwtEvent, обратное неверно.

Если такой параметр в библиотеке по ошибке автора, то можно попробовать отнаследоваться от MouseDownEvent, если это возможно (он вроде как не final), для того, чтобы создавать его. Мы сможем создать public-конструктор и вызывать через super() protected-конструктор основного класса. И переопределить методы get-что-то-там на те значения, которые пришли с событием до выполнения таймера. И использовать как обертку. Не факт, что это возможно. Проверить сейчас не могу.

Comment: Думаю это возможно, но могут быть неприятности из-за getType. К тому же, это жуткий хак. Лучше бы без него.

Comment: Про e != null я сначала подумал, потому что заподозрил, что возможно вызов обработчика ивента сделан как-нибудь неправильно. Я не вижу аннотации UiBinder'а, а значит, обработчик подписан как-то иначе.

Comment: Пробовал от наследоваться, ничего хорошего не вышло. Не падает, но и не работает так, как задумано.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, поможет ли это Вам, но я обнаружил следующее: (в GwtEven.java)

```
  /**
   * Asserts that the event still should be accessed. All events are considered
   * to be "dead" after their original handler manager finishes firing them. An
   * event can be revived by calling {@link GwtEvent#revive()}.
   */
  protected void assertLive() {
    assert (!dead) : "This event has already finished being processed by its original handler manager, so you can no longer access it";
  }
```